# height:100% mysteriously not working

Tags: html, css

I'm building some tests around height:100%.

On the [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/7jDFD/14/) page you can notice the blue area doesn't stretch its height with the page content, even though it is assigned to have the CSS style of:

```
height:100%;
```

Any help on solving or trying to understand this behaviour?

Comment: Your text goes over the 100% height. Just remove that line and it should go down to meet with your clear:both; Also, change your <section> to a <div> if it still wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `height: auto` on your `body` element,

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Update**

Ok, wasn't aware it needs to be 100% despite lesser content.

What you can do is,

give your body some height (say 1000px). And then the 100% on your `section` will expand to 1000px.

PS: `min-height` won't work. You'll need to provide a height in `px` or `em`.

Although, I'm not very sure on why elements cant figure out 100% of 1000px and NOT 100% of 100%

Comment: That seems to work, but can add an explanation of why it works?

Comment: Because you set the height at a specific height and he doesn't, so it works. Like magic.

Comment: I am sorry, it doesn't work. I thought it did, but it doesn't, look at the same example with less content: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/7jDFD/10/

Answer (score 1):

If you want that section to always be 100% height, you could use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%`. If not, you'll have to give the parent a height (like the html), and then use `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

the theory behind the behaviour is that if you want to have an element filling the 100% height of a window, you have to make sure that parents of such element also fill 100% of the browser window .

The idea is clear, if you are setting 100% height, you have to ask: 100% of what exactly?

The answer is of a parent.

Of course, this applies to elements without the `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` which are not in the "flow" of the document.

An illustration of the problem is very clearly seen in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVKnJ/

I hope it enlightens a bit.

EDIT:

is this the desired behaviour?

you indeed have to use `height: 100%` for containers (html, body) and `min-height: 100%` for the elements you expect to exceed the height of the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jDFD/15/

Comment: My problem is not on understand that, just multiply the text in you file's blue column, until it passes the screen height, the blue area, and the green one stop right where the screen ends. - http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/AVKnJ/1/

Comment: I suppose the problem in this case was just clearing the floats of .col by using, for instance, display: table on the container. But the height works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/AVKnJ/3/

Comment: What about if I want the red div's height to stretch with the page height too?