# An issue with height:100%;

Tags: html, css

I'm building some tests around height:100%.

On the [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/7jDFD/11/) page you can notice the blue area doesn't stretch its height with the page content, even though it is assigned to have the CSS style of:

```
html{ height:100%; }
body{ height:auto; }
```

i've unsuccessfully tried:

```
body{ height:100%; }
```

Any help on solving or trying to understand this behaviour?

Comment: You asked a similar question:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562211/height100-mysteriously-not-working/18562226#18562226

Comment: This is standard css behavior, an html document is only as long as its content, there are css solutions to, for example, placing the footer at the bottom of the browser but this is often achieved with javascript

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is known as "faux columns" and unfortunately the answer isn't `height: 100%`. This issue has been covered at length by many bloggers/developers, but the best roundup of the various techniques I've found is in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) by Chris Coyier at CSS Tricks. It specifically addresses faux columns in fluid layouts, which is what you're trying to do in your fiddle.

Here's a demo from the article on Coyier's great [CodePen](http://codepen.io) website:

http://codepen.io/cantera25/pen/lILha

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this is related to what I've asked above.

Comment: You're mistaken. Good luck, hope you find what you need.